# Importing CSV table - Error

Tags: tables, datatool

I am new to LaTeX and am compiling a document right now using TeXworks. I am trying to create CSV tables into my document right now, and although I succeed in between I must have some small bug in the code which I just cannot spot (trust me I looked for hours).

My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}

% Load packages

%************************************************************

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=0.75in,rmargin=0.75in}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{datatool} % Allows importing tables
\usepackage{enumerate} % Allows latin I option

\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{2pt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}



\DTLsetseparator{,}
\DTLloaddb{tarea}{table_test.csv}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Area}
  \centering
  \DTLdisplaydb{tarea}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Latex gives me the following errors:**

Error 1

```
undefined
34
! Argument of \@dtl@trim has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.34 \beginstable}
```

Error 2

```
undefined
?
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [9pt].
```

Error 3

```
undefined
?
Package geometry Warning: The marginal notes overrun the paper.
     Add 21.7975pt and more to the right margin.
```

Comment: I never even knew you could do that with LaTeX so I'm afraid I'm not of much help here but if you don't need to load changing tables over and over again but just have one table that you want to show in a document, you can import CSV in gnumeric and export it as LaTeX document or LaTeX fragment. That would also allow some formatting in the table (which you can then do WYSIWYG-style).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: @Max: Could you provide a dummy sample of your datafile?

Comment: Errors 2 & 3 are not really errors but warnings. That aside, Could you give more detail (in terms of the `.log` output) for error 1? What is written before "undefined"?

Comment: As Jake says, we really need the `table_test.csv` file. I understand if that you may not want to provide that complete file, but what I would recommend is that you start removing chunks of that file until the error goes away - then you know that the problem was in the last chunk you deleted. Repeat this process until you are able to get the `table_test.csv` as small as possible. If the problem is not obvious, you could post that here, and change any confidential text.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I actually do need to load changing tables. Replicability is key! Anyway, I found my mistake. my variable name had a underscore in it which obviously needs to be marked as /_!

Answer (score 4):

May I suggest you to use pgfplotstable? It works great with CSV files and gives you a lot 
of control. Here's a nice example:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
% recommended:
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\pgfplotstableset{col sep=comma}

\begin{document}



\begin{table}
\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[%
    % Sort the values 
    sort, sort key=error2,
    %
    % The columns to be printed
    columns={dof,error1,{grad(log(dof),log(error2))}},
    %
    % Columns styles
    columns/error1/.style={
        % Name
        column name=$L_2$,
        % Notation and padding
        sci,sci zerofill, sci subscript,
        precision=3},
    columns/dof/.style={
        sci, sci sep align, 
        column name=\textsc{Dof}},
    columns/{grad(log(dof),log(error2))}/.style={
        column name=slopes $L_2$,
        fixed, fixed zerofill,
        % Align decimal deparators
        dec sep align, 
        precision=1},
    %
    % Some colors.
    every even row/.style={
        before row={\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}}},
    every head row/.style={
        before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomrule},
        ]{data.csv}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Nice and neat table]