# How to make table creation in TeX easier?

Tags: tables

In my work I need to describe several database tables (~20) - each table has six columns - field name, field type, key, null / not null setting, default value and description.

Is there some way how to create in TeX some kind of template / macro so I don't need to create each table manually?

Comment: Do you want to read in the table and typeset automatically? For instance `pgfplotstable` could be a viable solution?

Comment: Along the lines of `pgfplotstable`: [importing csv table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53137/importing-csv-table-error).

Answer (score 1):

If you already have tables in Excel, you could use the plugin Excel2LaTeX to convert everything immediately to LaTeX.

Comment: While your idea is nice, we prefer the answers to be "self-contained", i.e. to explain in more detail how such a conversion is done. Could you please add a small example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RStudio` to type your LaTeX document with `knitr`, `R` and the `xtable` package, in that way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}    
<<echo=FALSE,results='asis'>>=
library("xtable")
my_tab=read.csv("database_table.csv")
tab=xtable(my_tab)
print(tab)
@
\end{document}
```

with many possible output options. You can use a `for` loop if you want to write it for 20 tables.